# how to update vue object value inside this object

Tags: javascript, rest, api, vue.js, axios

I create Vue object and need update some data when get response

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        message: [1,2,3,]
    },
    methods: {
        getList: function () {
            var myGet = axios.get('/api/guests/.json')
                .then(function (response) {                    
// ????????? message = response.data;

                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });            
        }
    },
    created:function () {
        this.getList();
    }
});
```

how to update vue object value inside this object?
how to update 'message'  ?

Comment: this.data.message = response.data;

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the correct context to your `then` callback and access `this.message`. You will have to do something like this

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        message: [1,2,3,]
    },
    methods: {
        getList: function () {
            var myGet = axios.get('/api/guests/.json')
                .then(function (response) {                    
                    this.message = response.data;
                }.bind(this))
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });            
        }
    },
    created:function () {
        this.getList();
    }
});
```